# How can I select the count of rows as a subquery of results from main query

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I am trying to gather the amount of items at a place only if the `WHERE places.x < 5` is true. The reason for this, is that both the `at_places` and `places` tables contains tens of thousands of rows.

This is a general idea of what I'm trying to do; but I am unable to test it as it takes quite a long time to finish. I figure that being able to contain both the grabbing of count and the places in one query would be quite a bit faster than running a subsequent query grabbing the count for each place returned.

```
SELECT  `places`.`id`, 
        `places`.`name`,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `at_places` WHERE places_id=places.id) AS count
FROM `places`
WHERE places.x < 5
```

Comment: This query shouldn't take that long.  Do you have indexes on the `at_places.id`, `places.id` and `places.x` fields?

Comment: Only on the ids. I have a bunch more things that are being compared to reduce down the places list, just used x as a placeholder for clarity.

Comment: It still may help speed up your query if you index on the fields you're using in your `WHERE` clause.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see what indexes are being used.

Comment: I considered it. My main issue would be that the at_places change atleast daily, sometimes more often. I think the slowdown of insert would outweigh the benefits? But perhaps not, I suppose I could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that an explicit join works better:

```
select p.id, p.name, ap.cnt
from places p join
     (select ap.places_id, count(*) as cnt from at_places ap group by ap.places_id) ap
     on p.id = ap.places_id
where p.x < 5
```

I believe your performance problem is due to the fact that the subquery is executed once for each row in the outer query.  An index on `at_places.places_id` should also speed up the query.

Comment: No, I am looking for the count of rows of the at_places table which have the same id as the place row appended onto the result as a count column. (Sounds rough I'll draw)


====result for query====
id | name | count

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I tried to edit your answer but it got rejected. The only thing about this that needs to be different is that `ap.cnt` should be added to the select clause at the top- otherwise it only lists id & name on the rows. But works great. Cheers.